# Redux: Dispatching an action that is not affecting the state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

We handle side-effects in middlewares, not in reducers, which means we always need to dispatch an action to handle side-effects. **Do you think it's proper to dispatch an action, which is not changing the state, to make an API call?** I've always avoided it because `Action` stands for changing the `State` in my understanding.

Comment: You can use a concept of action generataor

Answer (score 0):

I am also handling it in my projects just like you described (only dispatching Actions, which are changing the state, but also having an side effect for api calls).

Whats wrong with doing so, but you have the additional attributes `loading` and `loaded` in your state?

So within your reducer function for the initial Action, you would only set `loading = true` and trigger the side effect.

Within the reducer function for the `Success Action` you would set your state like this:

```
return {
  ...state,
  data: action.payload,
  loading: false,
  loaded: true
};
```

This also has the advantage that you can easily display a loading indicator, if your rest call takes a while.

Comment: I do have `loading` and `loaded` state. But in some case, we don't need to have the state if don't need to display UI for it. And since all logics are located in my middleware, redux-saga for example, I was wondering if it's alright to dispatch an action just for running those middlewares.

Comment: Then I would say it depends on your personal preferences, but what is the alternative? How do you trigger the side effect without dispatching the initial `REQUEST_ACTION` ?

Comment: I created a function and call it in the component, and used this function in the middleware too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use action generators which may or may not dispatch actions as per your need

This is a action generator which is used to remove a library item from store on a condition that if it is found on the server otherwise not

```
export const startRemoveLibraryItem = (libraryItemId) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return database.ref(`library/libraryItems/${libraryItemId}`)
                .then((snap) => {

                    // if item found on server I am going to dispatch a action now
                    if(snap.val() == something)
                       dispatch(removeLibraryItem(libraryItemId));
                })
                .catch((e) => {
                    // item some error do not do anything
                    console.log('Error in removing Library Item..');
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, we can use action creators, but I don't use redux-thunk. I'd rather watch actions to handle side-effects. All logic that handles side-effects is in middlewares.

Comment: what do you mean by side-effects? It is rather a new term for me in react

Comment: Well, it can be many things such as making AJAX call, storing data in localStorage. Things that are not guaranteed to return the same output of the given input. Things that shouldn't be in components nor reducers.

Comment: In my view you can use actions for you job. You can do all sort of side-effect in there and dispatch empty actions or unknown action. Actions are meant to be doing some action for some stimulus so I believe it would not violate any definitions.